# How to check a condition against all the columns of a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which has more than 30 columns(all are varchar). I need to list out all the columns which contains blank i.e.' ' values.

I tried using 'coalesce' but it is only for NULL.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is not as clear as you think it is.

Comment: i need to check how many columns in a table contains value ' ', like we check for individual column like select * from tbl where col1=' '

Comment: Please provide an example, still not clear with your problem

Comment: @user2919579 . . . "how many columns" is very different from "list out all columns".  See why other people might be confused?  Are you looking at this information on each row?  Or whether a column contains a blank value in any row?  Or whether all columns are blank in a column?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following query will give you all the columns in a table that might have `null` or `''` values.
It is written so that you can run it for all tables in your database but you can limit it to a single table, as I have done for this specific example, checking a table called `testingNulls`:

```
--two variables needed for table name and column name, when looping through all tables
declare @table varchar(255), @col varchar(255), @sql varchar(max)

--this will be used to store the result, to have one result set instead of one row per each cursor cycle
if object_id('tempdb..#nullcolumns') is not null drop table #nullcolumns
create table #nullcolumns (tablename varchar(255), columnname varchar(255))

declare getinfo cursor for
select t.name tablename, c.name 
from sys.tables t join sys.columns c on t.object_id = c.object_id 
where t.name = 'testingnulls' --here the condition for the table name
open getinfo
fetch next from getinfo into @table, @col
while @@fetch_status = 0
begin
  select @sql = 'if exists (select top 1 * from [' + @table + '] where [' + @col + '] is null or [' + @col + '] like '''' ) begin insert into #nullcolumns select ''' + @table + ''' as tablename, ''' + @col + ''' as all_nulls end'
  print(@sql)
  exec(@sql)
  fetch next from getinfo into @table, @col
end
close getinfo
deallocate getinfo

--this should be the result you need:
select * from #nullcolumns
```

You can see a working example [here](http://rextester.com/DGVIH35864). I hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

List all columns that contain a blank in some record? You'd use a query per column and collect the results with `UNION ALL`:

```
select 'COL1' where exists (select * from mytable where col1 like '% %')
union all
select 'COL2' where exists (select * from mytable where col2 like '% %')
union all
...
union all
select 'COL30' where exists (select * from mytable where col30 like '% %');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want like *`select * from [your_table_name] where [col1] = '' and [col2] = ''.....`*, then use dynamic sql query like below.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);
select @sql = 'select * from [your_table_name] where ' 
    + stuff((
            select ' and [' + [column_name] + '] = ' + char(39) + char(39)
            from information_schema.columns
            where table_name = 'your_table_name'
            for xml path('')
    ) 
    , 1, 5, ''
);

exec(@sql);
```

---

### **Update**

Or else if you want to list the column names which have a blank value, then you can use the below dynamic sql query.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);
select @sql = stuff((
        select ' union all select ' + [column_name] + ' as [col1], ' 
        + char(39) + [column_name] + char(39) + ' as [col2]'
        + ' from your_table_name'
        from information_schema.columns
        where table_name = 'your_table_name'
        for xml path('')
    )
    , 1, 11, ''
); 

set @sql = 'select distinct t.col2 as [blank_cols] from(' + @sql 
+ ')t 
where coalesce(ltrim(rtrim(t.col1)), ' + char(39) + char(39) + ') = ' 
+ char(39) + char(39) + ';';

exec(@sql);
```

**[Find a demo here](http://rextester.com/XJGBE6614)**

But still I'm not sure that this is what you are looking out for.

Answer (score 1):

you have not many choices but to specify all the columns in your where clause

```
WHERE COL1 = '' AND COL2 = '' AND COL3 = '' AND . . .
```

or you can use Dynamic SQL to form your query, but that is not an easy path to go

Comment: thanks, i'll try to build dynamic SQL. I thought there might be some way.

Comment: I think you meant `... OR ...` instead of `... AND ...` but even then it's not the answer to the question...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count number of columns having '' value in a table (not for each row) then use the following

```
SELECT max(CASE WHEN col1 = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
       max(CASE WHEN col2 = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
       max(CASE WHEN col3 = '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
       ...
FROM t
```

[demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a818a175dcff706b2479fbf9add963a5)

Comment: What if we have 500 columns? Does it make sense to use your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I created a dynamic SQL script that you can use by providing the table name only
Here it is

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
declare @table sysname = 'ProductAttributes'

select @sql = 
    'select * from ' + @table + ' where ' +
    string_agg('[' + name + '] = '' '' ', ' and ')
from sys.columns 
where object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table)

select @sql

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Unfortunately, for [SQL string concatenation String_Agg function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/string-aggregation-function-to-concatenate-in-sql-server-2017.aspx) is new with SQL Server 2017
But it is also possible to use [SQL XML Path to concatenate](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/concatenate-using-xml-path.aspx) WHERE clause fragments

```
SELECT  @sql = 'select * from ' + @table + ' where ' +
  STUFF(
    (
    SELECT
      ' and ' + '[' + [name] + '] = '' '' '
    from sys.columns 
    where object_id = OBJECT_ID(@table)
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
    ).value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)'
    ), 1, 5, ''
  )

select @sql as sqlscript
exec sp_executesql @sql
```